# Necessary to tape ceiling-wall joint if installing moulding?

Tags: drywall

Just got my drywall up in a room that I will be installing crown moulding in.

Is taping the joints where the ceiling meets the wall necessary if its just going to be covered up? I've heard mixed answers, some including just using a single layer of firetape.

Comment: The only joints it's _necessary_ to tape are in firewalls, such as between the home and an attached garage. Everything else is discretionary.

Answer (score 6):

You can do what you like unless local codes require otherwise.

It does not have to be *pretty*, since it will be hidden, but two benefits of bothering to tape and mud the joint (at least crudely) are better fire performance and not making life easier for your insect friends crawling around the house. A third would be somewhat less air leakage.

Comment: If the joint is taped and mudded then  fire will perform better?  ;)

Comment: The joint will perform better in the even of a fire - i.e. the fire will spread more slowly. When we speak of "fire performance" in buildings, that is the generally accepted meaning of the term - burn worse, not burn better.